# PgAdmin remoto a postgres

Tags: postgresql

Estoy tratando de conectar remotamente a postgres con pgadmin , ya configure los archivos (listen_addresses = '*') y (host mibasededatos miusuario 0.0.0.0/24 md5), abri el puerto 5432 en el firewall en ambas pc, le di permiso a todos los programas en el firewall de windos para recibir conexiones de cualquier ip pero recibo el siguiente mensaje:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host "190.171.102.95" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Alguien puede guiarme?

Comment: Reiniciaste el servicio de Postgres luego de configurar esos archivos?

Comment: ¿Que sistema operativo es? ¿Reiniciaste o recargaste el firewall?

Comment: Correcto si lo hice, reinicie el servicio de postgres. @DrakoRod Es una sistema operativo windows 10 enterprise de 64 bits. Ya intente todo lo visto en internet y no hay forma.

Comment: Ya desactivaste el firewall? o permiteste el puerto?

Comment: Ya hice todo eso